# Does Object implement the IEnumerable interface C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Developer 
{
    public string Name;
    public string Language;
    public int Age;
}

class App {
    static void Main() {
        Developer[] developers = new Developer[] {
            new Developer {Name = "Paolo", Language = "C#"},
            new Developer {Name = "Marco", Language = "C#"},
            new Developer {Name = "Frank", Language = "VB.NET"}};
        var developersUsingCSharp = from d in developers
                                    where d.Language == "C#"
                                    select d.Name;
        foreach (var item in developersUsingCSharp) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have not explicitly implemented the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. My question is the from clause will take instances of types that implement the IEnumerable interface, but in this case it is a user defined type of Developer class

The sample code is taken from LINQ in Microsoft .NET Framework Book.

Comment: You are using the `foreach` on `developersUsingCSharp`, which is an `IEnumerable<string>`. The `var` keyword does not mean "This type is `Object`", it means "I'll let the compiler decide what the type is". You should avoid using var, because of confusions like this one.

Comment: `var` has some definite advantages. I would hesitate to advise someone to avoid using it entirely. But there is value in using explicit declarations until you have a firm grasp on types in .NET.

Comment: @Joushua i thought i had edited the question. My question is the from clause will take instances of types that implement the IEnumerable<t> interface, but in this case it is a user defined type of Developer class.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault He shouldn't avoid using the `var` keyword, he should learn what the `var` keyword does and what its advantages and disadvantages are and make an informed decision on when it's appropriate to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`System.Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) (which is what you're creating when using the `Developer[]` notation, Implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide a suitable link to read on this connection.

Comment: @ckv the linked MSDN article contains a lot of information about that. Do how have a specific question?

Comment: I get it now. So that was the missing connection i did not know about.

Answer (score 2):

By virtue of the fact that your assigning the variable `developersUsingCSharp` to the result of a linq query, it is of type `IEnumerable<string>` (it would be an `IQueryable<string>` if this was a entity framework query or something similar).

Perhaps it's hard to analyze exactly what's happening with the query syntax. The query:

```
var developersUsingCSharp =
    from d in developers
    where d.Language == "C#"
    select d.Name;
```

Is equivalent to the fluent syntax:

```
var developersUsingCSharp =
    developers.Where(d => d.Language == "C#")
              .Select(d => d.Name);
```

The Linq [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) and [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) extension methods both accept `IEnumerable<T>` and return `IEnumerable<T>` as a result. So you can can definitely use `foreach` on the result.

Comment: Added comment to my question. I have rephrased my question.

Comment: @ckv I had assumed the confusion was with the linq query, not with the earlier array declaration. It seems [*HighCore*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17257579/1715579) has provided a sufficient answer to explain why arrays are enumerable, but I'll leave my answer here for the sake of completeness.